# I think moderators start to close every single question possible before the election to gain rep

Tags: discussion, reputation, closed-questions, election

I'm looking at closed questions by moderators that nominate at current election, and I feel like 70% of question the closed are usual questions, with no real reason to close them.

I have   checked more then 100 last closed question. I could share the links, but do not want to do this work again to collect them. I think you might have better tools to analyze this.

Could you do something with this.

The last closed question [Passing data from one Form to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15100552/235715)

I'm choosing this just because the link was in my clipboard because I have used it during discussion on election page.

Comment: Please show at least some of the questions you feel were unjustly closed. Nothing automated can judge that.

Comment: To gain rep? Closing doesn't award you reputation.

Comment: 70%? Really? What would we have to gain from that? As a moderator candidate, we know our recent history is being watched. Why would we risk our campaign by casting false close votes? That truly doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Yannis I don't know what they gain (I'm not very intereseted how this works) Flag, Rep, Stars, Diamonds, I don't care.

Comment: And which moderators are nominating? You realise that mods don't need to nominate, right? Except for pro-tems.

Comment: All actions (by non-moderators) are subject to community review and usually require several other participants. The *last* thing a candidate would want is to have a host of recent, disputed flags; nor would they want good, popular questions closed with their name attached. Adding to that, I've seen the work of nearly all the candidates and they are decent, honest people who care about the quality of the site. They're the ones who are willing to commit a large amount of time to *stopping* such practices.

Comment: Closure doesn't award you _anything_. Only the satisfaction that you helped keep the signal to noise ratio high.

Comment: @RoryAlsop You could "find fault in my words" (google translation of my native language term) or think on what I have said.

Comment: @Mat I have posted you the last link I had

Comment: I see no issue with that closure. "There is an error" with no error message is completely useless. Also note that some of those close votes could have been cast on the first revision of the post which is anything but clear.

Comment: 14 downvote without a single upvote says community is not agree with you view at all ...

Comment: @NullPointer it's not community, thr real community who uses this site doesn't know or care about meta site, I tell you more most of them is not even registered users of SO. In my development department (we have lot's of developers) all use SO in read only mode, I'm the only one registered user. So N down votes mean nothing, or that your small moderating community have rotten

Comment: @AlexBurtsev *Lots* of people use Stack Overflow in that way. It is in fact set up largely to be used that way. And there are some great reasons why it is so effective for those people. They come here, rather than Yahoo! Answers or ExpertSexChange (sic) for many reasons. I'll leave those reasons up for the reader's imagination, because I'm *positive* you will disagree with me on them.

Comment: @AndrewBarber they do not come here directly, they come here from google. BTW your new search engine is awful, I can't find anything using it, so even when I need to search something on SO i use google now.

Comment: Of course they come here from Google... where else would they come here by? The efforts put in by the dev team on SEO, and the *quality* of the content, have caused SO to be a very high result on so many Google searches. That's all *part of the plan*. As for the search engine; there are posts here about that, if you are interested. Or not; up to you!

Comment: *"I feel like 70% of question the closed are usual questions, with no real reason to close them."* Did you know 90% of statistics are made up on the spot? =oP

Comment: @crypticツ Including *that one*?  ;-)

Comment: Related: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AhFg8.png

Comment: This is hilarious, because it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You know what's kind of sad, actually? I didn't vote to close *this*!

Comment: @Andrew Barber: Well, it's *moderators* he's referring to and not moderator *candidates*, so...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Actually, I'm 90% sure he's talking about candidates; he just worded that clumsily. He was in Flexo's nomination saying we both close questions that shouldn't be, and the example he used here is the one he used there (one I voted to close)

Comment: @Andrew Barber: I know - that was simply a joke excuse for me to say that this rant is in fact not constructive ;)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Ack! HAHA! OK, I need sleep. I'm off to see the wizard! Nothing to see here...

Comment: The fact is the question was closed with 3 answers, one accepted with 4 upvotes now, and another one from one of the users who also voted to close it, which seems somehow an incoherent behavior. So how can that question be "not a real question"?  It doesn't make much sense, to me at least.  I've seen many questions closed with no valid reason in my opinion, in the 5 months or so of being a registered user.  By no means I suggest moderators or candidates are closing questions with a hidden purpose, but the actual closing process can generate all kind of conclusions.

Comment: @faa Basically, the answers to that question were guesses. They were *good* guesses, granted; but when I voted, I honestly had no clue what the question was asking. At all. (and I know that technology - though no knowledge of it was needed to be confused about what the question was actually asking). Regardless: other people can reopen it, if need be.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks for the comment. I understand your reasons and that happens to me very often with .htaccess and mod_rewrite questions, but something is not working and I guess is because the messages don't explain the technical reasons behind the closing. Maybe that's something that could be improved in the future, also stopping people without enough information voting to close questions they don't have a clue what are about.

Comment: `I don't know what they gain (I'm not very intereseted how this works) Flag, Rep, Stars, Diamonds, I don't care.` If you don't care enough to learn what you're talking about, don't whine on Meta about it.

Answer (score 22):

Since you were 'discussing' this topic with me under Flexo's nomination, and I am a candidate, I can only assume you mean I am among those you are speaking of, here. If I am wrong about my assumption, I'll be happy to acknowledge that fact...

But your claim is *wrong*, and slightly offensive.

I vote to close (and flag) because I believe the things I am voting/flagging on deserve it. I get no rep from it. You can examine my history if you like, and you will find that I certainly have not been 'suddenly' voting to close and flagging things. I've been doing it for a long time, because I *want* to do it.

I've run for moderator two times before this, and after each time, I continue flagging and voting just as I did before.

I see no reason whatsoever to think any of the other candidates would think and act any differently than I have described myself, here.

Clearly, you disagree with the closings/flaggings. That's your right. However, I strongly disagree with you about that topic, in general.

Comment: I have no right to disagree about closing. The Question is closed, I can;t do anything about it, I can't vote for reopen, nor I can vote for unti-close.

Comment: @AlexBurtsev You only need 305 rep more to be able to vote to re-open.

Comment: @Yannis I see no option for voting to reopen on this question.

Comment: @Alex Burtsev: you _can_ do something about it. You can flag and explain why you think the question was wrongly closed/deserves re-opening. (And the mod nominees don't see the flags, so you're safe from whatever devious plot they might be running.)

Comment: Ahh, I have missed the MORE word.

Comment: +1, which gives you another gold badge :D

Comment: @Doorknob Awww - Yeah!!!