# What counts as "not constructive" on Meta Stack Overflow these days?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, not-constructive

Over the last couple of weeks, I have found myself wondering about the closure (or near-closure) of some questions on Meta. All of these questions were closed as "not constructive". And in each instance I thought "what exactly isn't constructive about this question?". Especially within the context of Meta.

Some recent examples of what I'm referring to are:

- [Does the tag system need revamping?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170678/does-the-tag-system-need-revamping) (3 votes so far)
- [Where can I find out more about the process of tag cleanup on a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170827/where-can-i-find-out-more-about-the-process-of-tag-cleanup-on-a-stack-exchange-s) (3 votes so far)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/what-is-done-to-extend-outreach-to-other-countries-and-yes-women (by now deleted, so 10k only)
- [What do you think of this suggested edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170849/what-do-you-think-of-this-suggested-edit) (4 such votes so far)

And I remember commenting on a couple of others. I'm not suggesting that this is a recent change on Meta. Perhaps nothing changed at all. It is merely something I noticed and paid attention to.

To be honest, I just don't get it. Not all of the questions are great, some have content I disagree with (and I have left comments indicating that), but I don't see how they are "not constructive". Especially on Meta, where discussion is allowed and welcomed (if on-topic).

So my questions are:

- What makes these posts "not constructive"?
- Should these really be closed? Or put in another way, what is the problem in leaving them opened?
- Are we perhaps using this reason to replace/create a close reason we're missing?
- Do we use it to indicate a question/discussion has "run its course"?
- Are we perhaps using it to indicate disagreement?

I would love to hear your thoughts. I have been called out for close votes before which were misinterpreted, so who knows what I'm overlooking in this instance.

---

For reference, and for those who can't close - the Meta description for `not constructive`:

[image: not constructive]

Comment: Voting to close as "not constructive". Cheap shot. I know.

Comment: @Oded, not cheap. Clearly this question will solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. Maybe we should be more subtle about these hints on meta.

Comment: I have to say that it seems to me there should definitely be a higher bar for 'Not Constructive' here. I disagree with that closing reason for most of the posts you have linked, except one.

Comment: @AndrewBarber "what do you think of this suggested edit"?

Comment: @Bart I think that was a joke; even if not, it was funny ;) But no; the one about countries and women.

Comment: It all comes down to the definition of "constructive" on Meta. As it stands, Meta **is** there to solicit debate or extended discussion. I am leaving off "arguments" as not constructive, though some community polling is still in the Meta remit.

Comment: @AndrewBarber got it right. T'was a joke (see, no close votes!) - my sense of humor gets in the way again!

Comment: @Oded No worries, I got that.

Comment: @Oded, yup, for instance `What makes these posts "not constructive"?` is actually constructive on meta (since it is meta). However, the close blurb is still the same as on the main site, right? (I can't see for myself since I cannot vote to close here.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yep, same thing

Comment: I'd vote to close the outreach question, disagree on the others. The outreach question isn't bad, but it blends two (imho) distinct issues in one, and that rarely works. The suggested edit one is borderline, I'm guessing some if not all of the close votes are for its first version.

Comment: @Bart, maybe changing it would be a step in the right direction then. Right now if I were to blindly follow these rules I would consider `What makes these posts "not constructive"?` the very definition of *not constructive*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah, that partially explains my sense of missing the appropriate close reasons. The absence of NARQ for example is sometimes a frustrating one. Though I can see that easily abused as well on Meta.

Comment: Meta is probably the one place where "not constructive" can be taken literally and applied to questions that aren't asked in good faith.

Comment: @AnnaLear Do any of the examples fail in that regard?

Comment: @Anna - or maybe too stupid to be taken seriously?  Like the question about opening up SE to women?  I'm sure you got a good laugh out of that :)

Comment: @AdamRackis Though that is so easily dismissed with a constructive answer and one of our lovely Meta specific "I disagree" downvotes.

Comment: [This was not constructive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169845/proposal-60-day-voluntary-abstention-from-down-voting)

Comment: @bart I think just the "what do you think of this suggested edit" question comes close to being not constructive, but that really only became apparent once the asker engaged in comments and it didn't look like he was interested in discussing the merits of that specific edit. The first two examples should not be closed, and the outreach question... I think it's intended well, though will probably go over like they always do. The way it's phrased I think is constructive enough.

Comment: "Not constructive" == "I don't like you or your question, and I want to see it closed."

Comment: @AnnaLear Yeah, we both have voiced our views on the "suggested edit" question. Though the underlying question "should non-native English speakers review suggested edits regarding language?" is a fair one. My answer (if written) would most likely not be appreciated by the OP, but that's another matter. I do agree though that of my examples that one is perhaps the most borderline due to behaviour.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm assuming there you mean "is used/abused as"?

Comment: @Pekka, but can we have that displayed as the reason for closing? It would be awesome, even for meta (although most probably wrong).

Comment: @Bart The irony of that question is that both you (if I'm not mistaken?) and I aren't native speakers, and yet... :)

Comment: @AnnaLear :) Nope, not a native speaker either.

Comment: @Anna may I ask what you are a native speaker of, if not English? I'm curious.

Comment: I thought "not constructive" was basically the new name of "noise or pointless".

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables It's especially not constructive because he hasn't updated his profile image to reflect the -51

Comment: @Pekka웃 Russian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically a Not Constructive close vote can mean any of the following:

- [It's a rant, not a question (even on Meta that's not okay)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169453/i-think-moderators-start-to-close-every-single-question-possible-before-the-elec)
- It's trolling or otherwise garbage, but not quite spam/off topic
- [Absolutely nothing good will come out of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96870/do-you-get-irked-by-the-attitude-on-se)
- [There's no point, no reasonable way to answer. It's just...what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169845/proposal-60-day-voluntary-abstention-from-down-voting)
- [It's just...really really stupid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)

It's in part used in these ways since there's no "not a real question" (or "noise or pointless") close reason, and, at least IMO, Meta really does need *some* way to close questions that aren't off topic (per se), aren't duplicates, but really **just aren't... constructive questions**. As Anna Lear said in a comment, it's basically being used literally on Meta, where otherwise it has a specific, SE defined purpose.

Sure, it's a big of a hack, but IMO Not Constructive matches many/most of the NC closures I see on Meta, certainly more than any other close reason.

As for those specific examples:

[Does the tag system need revamping?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170678/does-the-tag-system-need-revamping) is a pretty big question, almost just "do you think the tag system could be better" (can't everything be better?), though personally I wouldn't vote to close it.

[Where can I find out more about the process of tag cleanup on a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170827/where-can-i-find-out-more-about-the-process-of-tag-cleanup-on-a-stack-exchange-s) Is just poorly asked, IMO. I doubt it would have as many/any close votes if the title were just "how should one go about a tag cleanup".

[What do you think of this suggested edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170849/what-do-you-think-of-this-suggested-edit) Reads 60% like "why did Indians vote on my suggested edit" and 40% or less "what was actually wrong with this suggested edit". Once again I think it's the poor wording that kills it.

[What is done to extend outreach to other countries and, yes, women?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/what-is-done-to-extend-outreach-to-other-countries-and-yes-women) I find it hard to read this question (and it's assorted friends) as "SO why you so white/male/racist/sexist/English/etc". There's no suggestion here and IMO it's a pretty ridiculous question since, to my knowledge, there's really no ethnically/gender based targeting SE does to snag users...in fact most of it is purely organic. And this question, like several others on the topic, quickly devolves into not constructive name calling, defensive posts and generally pure drama that helps no one. I have no problem with the closure, and while I think deletion is a but much, I haven't voted to undelete.

Comment: Nice answer, but does it not illustrate part of my point? The first examples to me as well are clear cases. Though the "60 day abstention" one might be more NARQ to me. However, the latter examples and your evaluation of them might seem to indicate that we're a bit too heavy-handed with or "not constructive" votes? Or perhaps I just more easily read through and ignore the crap (where perhaps I shouldn't?).

Comment: My parents are why I'm so "white/male/racist/sexist/English(though not the proper form)", so perhaps that one could be moved to Meta.Parenting.SE? Certainly sounds like their fault.

Comment: @Bart Not all closures are clear cases, and, just like on the main site, I think some of these could have been saved by edits (especially the ones that aren't even closed). I think the majority of NC closures are probably right. There's some votes I don't really agree with, but I don't think it's being used incorrectly on the whole, or even most of the time

Comment: @Bart: I'm think all you've noted is that the rantier or more poorly worded they are the more likely they'll be closed. Perhaps a vote breakdown would reveal more of a spread than just pure NC.

Comment: @sixlettervariables That might well be the case. Especially for the "suggested edit" example, which I did try to edit into shape to prevent exactly what happened (without much success). Perhaps my overall threshold for "not constructive" is just a bit higher.

Comment: @Bart: I've +1'd your question because ultimately I agree that we shut down some stuff too quickly. However, Ben's answer (+1) does a good job explaining the Why's.