# What type of communities does Stack Exchange want to establish?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

At 100 sites and growing, Stack Exchange is becoming a host to many different communities with varying interests (and sizes). Is the aim of launching new sites, to make them (eventually) big communities like SO? Or are smaller and niche communities also considered desirable?

Also, what type of communities does SE consider desirable? Say, an open community with users of widely varying skill levels such as SO or a closed (unwelcoming to newbies) community of professionals* ?

---

*I am not implying that communities of professionals are unwelcoming to new users. In some cases, the standards set by such groups may be too strict for an amateur or a hobbyist (or may at least be *perceived* as such, which in effect does make it unwelcoming to a portion of new users).

Comment: Part of this is answered in the Area51 FAQ: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq And it's always good to keep in mind that SE is a company. And to some extent we (the users) are the product. The question then becomes whether or not it makes business sense to have a site around given a certain amount of users and activity.

Comment: @Bart, users are not a product of SE, SE is a product of the users, fascilitated by the company. Without users there is no SE.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe It works both ways, sure. But if something admittedly costs money to maintain, and you as the user are not paying for it...what is part of the product they end up selling? And I have no problem with that.

Comment: _"...or a closed (unwelcoming to newbies) community..."_ - you mean, such as [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/165773 "'Meta Stack Overflow doesn't like me...'")? :)

Comment: @gnat No, I was referring to another site. I havent had a *bad* experience here on MSO generally   http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/200868/ashrj?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=1 :)

Comment: You can have a professional audience that isn't "unwelcoming" to newbies. There's a large difference in being "unwelcoming" vs holding newbies to the same standards as everyone else.

Comment: @BenBrocka: there *is* a big difference, but in my experience a certain percentage of newbies will not be able to *percieve* that difference.

Comment: @JoachimSauer true but....at that point, there's not much you can do. No matter how nice you are, some will perceive quality standards as draconian or as a slight against them. It's all about making it clear to those who *will* understand, not fussing over those who won't no matter what you do.

Comment: @Bart I am interested in hearing the viewpoints with respect to *both* new communities (Area 51), as well as launched sites.

Comment: @AshRj Please don't bump your question with a single space. Either make some real changes or just award a bounty once you can.

Comment: Why is this being closed ?

Comment: It's all explained [here](http://stackexchange.com/about) very well. Quote: *You wouldn't shout out a calculus question in a football stadium, right? You'd go to the math department of a university. That's why instead of allowing questions on any topic, we bring together **individual communities of experts** on very specific topics. We welcome questions that are clear and specific, representing real problems that you face; **Stack Exchange is not the place for conversation, opinions, or socializing**.* Emphasis is mine and that's the answer to your question. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That discusses scope of sites, it doesn't cover the growth or size aspect. Is the target large SO like communities ? Or small highly spealized communities that *may* never reach SO size ?

Comment: @AshRj in my opinion it's obvious that Stack Exchange, as a money making company, is expecting each and every site to become as big as possible while preserving its expert nature. Expecting site to reach the size of Stack Overflow is bit of "overkill" but yeah, that's the general idea. I don't think there is a site designed in the first place to be only for small amount of people.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd *as big as possible while preserving its expert nature.* Thats a very ambigiuous and probably correct answer. To your second point, [smugmug.se], [poker.se], [bricks.se], [libraries.se] and [bitcoin.se] are some that I dont think can expand beyond a restricted number of people..

Comment: All those examples are still in Beta. I am sure that if they don't turn out to be viable, that they will not get out of beta. And a community can be small compared to SO, but if it still is one of the bigger sites for the community it represents, it might be of interest

Comment: @Bart *if it still is one of the bigger sites for the community it represents* .. So, there cannot be a definitive answer to my question, unless someone from SE chooses to respond. If we start scaling with respect to the sizes of the different communities that exist outside the network, then there simply cannot be a scale that could possibly be followed to evaluate or predict an expected site size generically (which is partly my question). Or I could be wrong to draw this conclusion  and there is some secret metric :)

Comment: This will provide some insight regarding Beta sites: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate

Comment: @Bart Thanks. That is the closest I will get as an answer to this question. It answers most of what I wanted to ask. I think I didnt frame this question as well as I could have. Why is this question not constructive ? Isn't discussing site ideology a function of meta ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170984/what-counts-as-not-constructive-on-meta-stack-overflow-these-days ;)