# Change the "not constructive" closure description on meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, not-a-real-question

The closure reason for "not constructive" on meta currently reads:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, **but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion**. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Isn't this a big part of meta? We have a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag solely for the purpose of soliciting debate and extended discussion.

This is more than a little silly. Please change.

Comment: Based on the way it's used here, it should be changed to, "I don't like this question. Therefore I'm closing it so it can be deleted."

Comment: @Mysticial: That's a very asinine way of looking at it. It is *very* possible for a discussion to be unconstructive. Have you read the [rant tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/rant/info)?

Comment: @animuson Unfortunately, having been on meta for over a year now, that's the impression that I have of it.

Comment: Meta is seemingly one of the few sites where "not constructive" actually means "not constructive". I've had similar thoughts before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170984/what-counts-as-not-constructive-on-meta-stack-overflow-these-days

Comment: Alright, I'm starting a bounty on the duplicate.

Comment: Or change it back to "noise or pointless"