# Why don't we have Not A Real Question on MSO?

Tags: feature-request, meta, close-reasons

From what I see, Not Constructive isn't a valid close reason because meta is *for* debate.

On the other hand, we get many vague/incomplete/what-the-hell-is-the-OP-trying-to-tell-us questions like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/180534/1) that probably need closing as NARQ. I see a couple such questions every week (there probably are many more). NC is used as a proxy to close these questions.

So, could we have NARQ on meta? It would be even better if NC was removed.

Note: The post initially asked for NC to be removed as well. On further thought, I've removed that bit.

Comment: Actually, Meta is about the only place where "Not constructive" actually means "not constructive".

Comment: 1) It seems like this is two requests, remove NC and add NARQ.  Do they need to be done in conjunction?  If not, they should probably be in two different posts. 2) Not constructive in MSO is generally not constructive in the general sense, whereas on SO it has a bit of a specialized definition.  On MSO it's not for any subjective/polling question, it's for trolling or questions where the intent is clearly not to generate a helpful answer.  That seems appropriate, and seems to be generally used appropriately (barring occasional exceptions).

Comment: @Bart: Well, that too. But IMO many of the times NC is used where the contstructiveness is debatable -- an objectively not constructive post is where there is no goal in sight but to malign a few users or the site.

Comment: Related btw: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170984/what-counts-as-not-constructive-on-meta-stack-overflow-these-days

Comment: @Servy: Well, the NC thing was an afterthought, mainly sprouting from my opinion that NARQ is much more useful than NC on meta.

Comment: Funny, I saw that exact link yesterday, and thought, "Where is the 'Not a Real Question' option when you need it?"

Comment: Thinking about the Meta application of either close reason, I feel it's a bit "six of one, half a dozen of the other". Does it ultimately really matter?

Comment: @Bart: That too. Still, I don't like hitting people with an NC ("Not Constructive" is slightly insulting when the question _is_ constructive) when the question is just hard to decipher.

Comment: @Manishearth If it's that hard to decipher then it's either NARQ or NC until it's fixed.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Exactly. Preferably NARQ.

Comment: I don't know who voted to close this as a duplicate of the question I linked but, even though it's somewhat related, it is certainly not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Questions are "not constructive" for many reasons–there's the part *before* the conjunction, too:

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise [...]

IMO that doesn't imply that there's no possibility of debate. I think answerers on MSO try to use facts and references when applicable, and specific expertise about SO/MSO in general.

I'm somewhat sympathetic to your concern regarding the *precise* verbiage as it applies to MSO, but it's overridden by the "spirit of the law".

Comment: Well, it's perfectly OK to have opinion-based (not fact-based) posts on MSO. I see what you mean, though..

Comment: @Manishearth Agreed, although I'd lump that under "specific expertise", where the expertise is meta in nature.

Comment: Anyway, updated q to remove the NC bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think because we include support questions.  If a user asks something vague, doesn't research their question first, is just complaining, etc., we have more of an obligation to help them than if they ask on SO.  It's a bit different of a culture for that reason.

In particular the "complaints" drive the point.  We usually can tease out a legitimate concern and address it and even retain the user, even though the complaint started as obviously NARQ.  Harder to do that if we close right away.

Comment: Note that "not a real question" *is* available on other meta sites

Comment: @ChrisF I have no idea why the inconsistency between this / other metas, then.